# Python and MySQLdb: substitution of table resulting in syntax error

Tags: python, mysql-python

I need to dynamically change tables and variables from time to time, so I wrote a python method like this:

```
    selectQ ="""SELECT * FROM  %s WHERE %s = %s;""" 
    self.db.execute(selectQ,(self.table,self.columnSpecName,idKey,))
    return self.db.store_result()
```

However this results in a syntax  error exception. I tried debugging it so I printed the variables in the method and filled them in manually, and that worked. So I am not sure what I am doing wrong ?

Is it because I try to use a substitute for a table ?

Also how do I debug mysqldb so it prints the substituted query as a string ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Parameter substitution in the DB API is only for values - not tables or fields. You'll need to use normal string substitution for those:

```
selectQ ="""SELECT * FROM  %s WHERE %s = %%s;""" % (self.table,self.columnSpecName)
self.db.execute(selectQ,(idKey,))
return self.db.store_result()
```

Note that the value placeholder has a double `%` - this is so that it's left alone by the initial string substitution.

Comment: If I understand correctly it will substitute the %s with a string and it will just drop off a % sign of %%s ?

Comment: ow btw, apperently you need to typecast the selectQ after substitution to string, but that might be because I also used some integers.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere?  In a query like `SHOW COLUMNS FROM Table`, it's no unreasonable to think of `Table` as a parameter.  (But +1 for the answer.  This is a hard question to search for.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full working example

```
def rtnwkpr(tick, table, col):

    import MySQLdb as mdb
    tickwild = tick + '%'       
    try:
        con = mdb.connect(host, user, password, db);
        cur = con.cursor()
        selectq = "SELECT price FROM %s WHERE %s LIKE %%s;" % (table, col)
        cur.execute(selectq,(tickwild))
        return cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: def inswk(table, total, date, tick): import MySQLdb as mdb import sys con = None try: con = mdb.connect(host, user, password, db); cur = con.cursor() selectq = """INSERT INTO %s (price, date, ticker) VALUES (%%s, %%s, %%s)""" % (table) cur.execute(selectq,(total, date, tick))

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use string substitution to add the table and column names, the driver will only handle parameters.

Ed: NM, Daniel answered faster and more completely

Answer (score -3):

Did you mean to write:

```
selectQ = """SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s = %s;""" % (self.table,self.columnSpecName,idKey) #maybe the idkey should be self.idkey? don't know the rest of the code

self.db.execute(selectQ)
```

and this is just a mistake with string formatting?

Btw why do you write explicit SQL for this kind of work? better use magical [sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) for python sql manipulation..