# Python MySQLdb variables as table names

Tags: python, mysql

I have a syntax error in my python which which stops MySQLdb from inserting into my database. The SQL insert is below.

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO %s (description, url) VALUES (%s, %s);", (table_name.encode("utf-8"), key.encode("utf-8"), data[key].encode("utf-8")))
```

I get the following error in my stack trace.

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your 
SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server 
version for the right syntax to use near ''four' (description, url) VALUES ('', 'http://imgur.com/a/V8sdH')' at line 1")
```

I would really appreciate assistance as I cannot figure this out.

EDIT:

Fixed it with the following line:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO " + table_name + " (description, url) VALUES (%s, %s);", (key.encode("utf-8"), data[key].encode("utf-8")))
```

Not the most sophisticated, but I hope to use it as a jumping off point.

Comment: Can you somehow show us the actual query which is being sent to MySQL?  My guess is that once you see it, it will be obvious what is wrong.

Comment: We'd need to see the SQL and probably the schema it's referencing to answer this.

Comment: Your code is short enough to post on here and not use a github link

Comment: I believe mgilson is right that table names cannot be parameterized. That seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like this is your SQL statement:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO %s (description, url) VALUES (%s, %s);", (table_name.encode("utf-8"), key.encode("utf-8"), data[key].encode("utf-8")))
```

IIRC, the [name of the table is **not** able to be parameterized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9394450/748858) (because it gets quoted improperly).  You'll need to inject that into the string some other way (preferably safely -- by checking that the table name requested matches a whitelisted set of table names)...  e.g.:

```
_TABLE_NAME_WHITELIST = frozenset(['four'])

...
if table_name not in _TABLE_NAME_WHITELIST:
    raise Exception('Probably better to define a specific exception for this...')

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO {table_name} (description, url) VALUES (%s, %s);".format(table_name=table_name),
    (table_name.encode("utf-8"),
     key.encode("utf-8"),
     data[key].encode("utf-8")))
```

Comment: That makes sense. I am new to this sort of stuff, are there resources for how I can sanitize any SQL statements I make? Specifically when using Python?

Comment: @TimothyPulliam -- The _safest_ thing is the whitelist that I've described above.  If _all_ tables should be writeable by anybody, then I suppose you could just query for a list of table names to build the whitelist.  If that doesn't work (and again, all table names are "safe" for a user to insert into), then I _think_ that checking the table name for any quote character (`'"`) and for semicolon is _probably_ good enough (but please don't take my word for it... I'm not a DB wrangler by trade) :-)